# Android editText help

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm writing an text converter app using an editText. I'va written code in the onTextChange method to replace text in the edittext. 
But when the replace is done the cursor moves to the begining of the text.
I managed to make it go to the end of the text. but thats not what i want. 
how can i get the last position of the cursor and set it there. using setSelection method. or any other way. help please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
Selection.setSelection(yourEditText, pos);
```

There you go. First line saves the position of the cursor in "pos" and second line sets your cursor to it. You can use yourEditText.setSelection(pos) if you prefer for the second line.

Comment: thxx man.. but now the cursor stays at 0 ... its doesnt move.. what should i do.. all the text appears infront of the cursor..

Comment: This doesnt work in my case. The setSelection() method seems to have no effect. My EditText view contains ImageSpans. Is there some other kind of workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
       (mTextView).setText(mData);
        int pos = (mTextView).getSelectionStart();
        (mTextView).setSelection(mData.length()+pos);
```